# Magento - 2 stores with differents shopping carts and differents search

Tags: magento, magento2

How can I configure Magento to have 2 stores with differents shopping carts and different search, but the same customers ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Not easily - you will need to moidy the internal API/ Realtionalal structure.. sounds nasty..

Comment: I have tried with 2 Websites like in this tutorial : http://www.zbeanztech.com/blog/managing-multiple-website-stores-magento but in this case the customers of the first Website can not login to the second Website, any solution in this way ?

Comment: You need to synchronise the users of each website using your own methods.. I don't think there is any in build functionality for this.. as a separate website was meant to be.. well - separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its rather easy

1. setup two different websites and store-views to separate the carts and searches
2. set up customer accounts to be global from system > configuration > customer > customer configuration

and the later is just $$$$ profit